# What will be the result of executing the following assembly code snippet?

Tags: assembly, x86, 16-bit

**Assembly code is:**

```
LAHF
AND AH,10H
JZ 50H
```

What will be the result?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `LAHF`?

Comment: The second Google result [explains exactly](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LAHF.html) what it does... "Load: AH ← EFLAGS(SF:ZF:0:AF:0:PF:1:CF)." It just copies the status of the FLAGS register into the ah register. The documentation above even explains which bit corresponds to which flag.

Answer (score 1):

`lahf` loads the flags register inside the `ah` register;

`and ah, 10h` performs an `and` with `10h`, masking out all the bits except the 5th, which is the [adjust flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjust_flag) from the flags register. The `and` also sets the flags, which are used in the instruction that follows.

`jz 50h` jumps to `50h` if the result of the `and` above was zero.

So, all in all it jumps to `50h` if the "[adjust flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjust_flag)" is not set, goes straight otherwise (clobbering `ah` in the process).